# Increasing visible text with on-click "read more"

Tags: javascript, jquery

What can I do better?

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";

    /*
     *  Header text. Vergroot de tekst door op lees meer te klikken
     */
    var heading = $(".header .text h2").height(),
        firstP = $(".header p:first").height(),
        areaSmall = heading + firstP,
        areaBig = $(".header .text").height(),
        box = $(".header .text"),
        readmore = $('.header .text a[title*="meer"]'),
        closeBox = $('.header .text a[title*="Sluit"]');

    $(".header .text").css({ height: areaSmall });

    readmore.click(function () {
        $(".header .text").animate({ height: areaBig }, 1000, "easeInQuart", function () {
            $(".header .text p").css({ visibility: "visible" });
        });
    });

    closeBox.click(function () {
        $(".header .text").animate({ height: areaSmall }, 1000, "easeOutQuart", function () {
            $(".header .text p").css({ visibility: "hidden" });
            $(".header .text p:first").css({ visibility: "visible" });
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have lots of calls to `$(".header .text")`, which you can replace with calls to `box`:

```
var areaBig = box.height();
```

Similarly, you can simplify calls to selectors within `box`, such as:

```
// Better than: readmore = $('.header .text a[title*="meer"]')
var readmore = box.find('a[title*="meer"]');

// Better than: $(".header .text").animate(...
box.animate({ height: areaBig }, 1000, "easeInQuart", function () {
  box.find("p").css({ visibility: "visible" });
});
```

These changes will not only make the code easier to read but also increase execution speed.

Comment: Just make sure that the definition of `box` comes first, or at least before any code that intends to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I would:

- call heights `height`s (or `"ht"`), as in areaSmall
- name jQuery object to start with `$`, and use them for elements I reference multiple times
- don't change names of things (header !== heading)
- don't create variables that are only used once
- remove unused variables (`box`)

Here's one take...

```
var $header = $('.header'),
    $text = $('.text', $header),
    $p = $('p', $text),
    areaSmallHt = $("h2", $text).height() + $("p:first", $header).height(),
    textHt = $text.height();

$text.css({ height: areaSmallHt });

$('a[title*="meer"]', $text).click(function () {
    $text.animate({ height: textHt }, 1000, "easeInQuart", function () {
        $p.css({ visibility: "visible" });
    });
});

$('a[title*="Sluit"]', $text).click(function () {
    $text.animate({ height: areaSmallHt }, 1000, "easeOutQuart", function () {
        $p.css({ visibility: "hidden" });
        $("p:first", $text).css({ visibility: "visible" });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what you want to be better but, for better code legibility and maintainability I would say that you should replace all your string constants with variables:

```
var headerClassId = ".header";
var textClassId = ".text";
var aTextValueThatMeansSomething = "easeInQuart";
```

Do the same with all other constants:

```
var aVariableNameThatMeansSomething = 1000;
...
$(headerClassId +" "+textClassId).animate({ height: areaBig },
      aVariableNameThatMeansSomething , aTextValueThatMeansSomething, function ...
```

Comment: This really doesn't do much for legibility.  `headerClassId +" "+textClassId` is less readable to me than `".header .text"` -- for one thing, because it requires that i know the value and intent of `headerClassId` and `textClassId`.  (Not to mention, `*ClassId` is a rather crappy name -- is it a class, or an id, or both?  "Either" is a bad answer.)